# System Center Configuration Manager 2007 - Debugging Client Installs

Tags: sccm, system-center

Having an issue installing the CCMsetup client on desktops.  The CCMSetup makes it to the PC, files are there, it gets added to the services for automatic start, it starts, but quits almost instantly.

Logs on the desktop show a entry like this.

```
<![LOG[Failed to successfully complete HTTP request. (StatusCode at WinHttpQueryHeaders: 404)]LOG]!><time="14:28:51.183+240" date="06-11-2009" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="2388" file="ccmsetup.cpp:5808">
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:  Firewall is off on both client and server.

Answer (score 2):

What command line are you using to start the install?  Try specifying a source directory with something like

```
ccmsetup.exe /source:\\server\SMSclient\i386 SMSSITECODE=AUTO
```

or

```
ccmsetup.exe /mp:server SMSSITECODE=AUTO
```

Note: these assume you have the site code setup in an AD GPO.

Are these Internet clients and a Native Mode site? If so, HTTPS needs to be setup, even though the log says HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your client has broken communication to the server, since it checks in with http. Not that the client service is not running. Check to see if http is blocked incoming to the server.

The client will check in to see what advertisements it has ect. and it sounds like that is not working.

Do you have the control panel icon "configuration manager"?

Does it have entries for configmgr site code?

Comment: No control panel icon, and the firewall isn't even on.  Is there a way for me to manually test connectivity?

Comment: If you've no control panel icon it didn't install. You said one firewall is off. Are both? Server and Client? Just to check for connectivity issue.